# Apache Commons Configuration: read from classpath/JAR?

Tags: java, configuration-files, apache-commons-config

Does the Apache Commons Configuration library support reading properties/configuration files from the classpath or JAR? I didn't find an API where it can take an `InputStream`, that returned by `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: this will solve your problem, filePath: configLocation  
```PropertiesConfiguration propertiesConfiguration = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                    .configure(new Parameters()
                            .properties()
                            .setFileName(configLocation)
                            .setListDelimiterHandler(new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(',')))
                    .getConfiguration();```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @dkb comment, and since there is not yet an answer to the question, you can do the following:

```
    Configuration configuration = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(
       PropertiesConfiguration.class)
          .configure(new Parameters()
                           .properties()
                           .setFileName("app.properties"))
          .getConfiguration());
```

You can also specify the location strategy that you want to use:

```
Configuration configuration = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration(
   PropertiesConfiguration.class)
      .configure(
          new Parameters()
                .properties()
                .setLocationStrategy(new ClasspathLocationStrategy())
                .setFileName("app.properties"))
       .getConfiguration());
```